# How do I make the comment disappear after deleting from the database?

Tags: functions, comments, comment-form, post-type, comments-template

I can delete the comment from the database with this code, however when the page is loaded again the comment will still be there. I need to update again to disappear.
How do I resolve this?

```
            <?php if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
                set_query_var( 'commentid1', $_POST['commentid'] );
                wp_delete_comment( get_query_var( 'commentid1'), true );    
            };
            ?>
            <form class="delete-comment" action="" method="post">
               <input type="hidden" name="commentid" value="<?php comment_ID() ?>" /> 
                <p align="right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" title="Delete" />
                </p>
            </form>
```

Comment: I'd guess it's cached somewhere then. What caching / CDNs do you have on your site? Can you clear all the caches that might contain the comment?

Comment: Tested in anonymous browser and continues.
The solution I found was to use the $_POST generated by the URL to notify the user that the comment was deleted (in a popup), so he can go back to the comments. 

`            <?php
            $textoc = $_POST["commentid"];
            if ($textoc > "0") : ?>
                comment deleted. <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>/#comments">Back to comments</a>
          <?php endif; ?> `

(#comments - I put anchor text on the page to go straight to the comments when the page reloads.)

Comment: Then it was probably cached on the server somewhere, or your CDN if you have one.

Comment: really. I will investigate this. Thank you very much.